# facebook request dialog how to get the request_ids

Tags: php, facebook

Say,i've an facebook application.I use facebook request dialog javascript sdk to send invite to my friend.

At my friend account,he get;s notification and clicks the invite and he give's permission for the app .here how do i get the request id.

I'm using the code that was present in fb docs but it is giving request id only in the second invite but not at first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request id's are delivered as a comma delimetered array.

You must use code like this to get them:

```
$r = $_REQUEST['request_ids'];

$rids = explode(',',$r);
```

$rids will now contain an array of your request ID's.

EDIT / UPDATE:

An example of what to do on your callback:

```
  function sendRequestToManyRecipients() {
    FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'Request'
    }, requestCallback);
  }

  function requestCallback(response) {
    top.location.href="REDIRECT_URL?req="+response.request_ids;
  }
```

In the PHP script that it redirects to you can now request the ID's that the user has invited to your app using `$_REQUEST['req']`

Comment: This should work, are you sure you have the redirect UI for the dialog set correctly?

Comment: When you put the code for the request dialog into your script, you must declare a `redirect ui` for the dialog or it won't know where to take you once you have selected your friends to send notifications to. NOTE: Request ID's are given to the user who uses the dialog... The user that accepts them in their app requests will ONLY send one request ID.

Comment: You are not handling the request ID's delivered from the user in the `requestCallback` function in your JS. Take another look at the developers site and use the `Redirect UI` method rather than an empty callback. IF you want a PHP script to manage the request id's it would be better to make an ajax call.

Comment: #DavidBArker:How to do that ajax call

Comment: Example edited, forgot to call the callback func. I've taken the FB example as that's what you had in your script already rather than my own.

Comment: You need to understand how the request ID's work: 1 user, using your app, opens up the request dialog and sends requests to his friends. On the callback, you recieve ALL the request ID's of people he sent to. When one of his friends ACCEPTS the request. His friend sends ONE REQUEST ID to your app that will be in the list you already have. You compare the two so you know who sent the request inititally and reward them however you want!